# how store multiple array value in data base?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMsuM.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd2uG.png)

```
model:

 function add_wliempmap($params)

{ 
   foreach ($params as$row) 
    {

    $this->db->insert('tbl_wli_peremp_map',$row);
    $query= $this->db->insert_id();
  // return$query->result();
}
}
controller:
 public function submit()
{   

   $data['data']=array('wid' => $this->input->post('wid'),'eid' => $this->input->post('eid')
                   );

    $this->Wliempmap_model->add_wliempmap($data);
        // var_dump($_REQUEST);
        // exit;

}
```

Above model $row variable have array value I want to store this variable value in database how to pass this variable in controller multiple value with example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as per bellow code:

Model:

```
public function add_wliempmap($params)
{ 
   $this->db->insert('tbl_wli_peremp_map',$params);
   return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function submit()
{   
   $data = array('wid' => $this->input->post('wid'),'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'));
   $this->Wliempmap_model->add_wliempmap($data);
}
```

For details info:

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data